# Leverage T-SQL newer capabilities to make query more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this **T-SQL** query written in a very basic and inefficient way:

```
SELECT
    e.ExchangeId,
    e.ExchangeName,
    s.StockId,
    s.StockName,
    sp.StockDate,
    sp.StockPrice,
    DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate) AS YearTDate,
    (SELECT spm.StockPrice FROM dbo.StockPrices spm WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (spm.StockId = sp.StockId) AND (spm.StockDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate))) AS YearTPrice,
    (SELECT TOP 1 spm.StockDate FROM dbo.StockPrices spm WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (spm.StockId = sp.StockId) AND (spm.StockDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate)) ORDER BY spm.StockPriceId) AS LatestDate,
    (SELECT TOP 1 spm.StockPrice FROM dbo.StockPrices spm WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (spm.StockId = sp.StockId) AND (spm.StockDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate)) ORDER BY spm.StockPriceId) AS LatestPrice,
    ((SELECT TOP 1 spm.StockPrice FROM dbo.StockPrices spm WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (spm.StockId = sp.StockId) AND (spm.StockDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate)) ORDER BY spm.StockPriceId) - sp.StockPrice) AS PL,
    CASE WHEN sp.StockPrice < (SELECT MIN(spm.StockPrice) FROM dbo.StockPrices spm WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (spm.StockId = sp.StockId) AND (spm.StockDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, sp.StockDate))) THEN 'Opportunity' ELSE 'None' END AS [Status]
FROM dbo.StockPrices sp WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Stocks s WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON s.StockId = sp.StockId
INNER JOIN dbo.Exchanges e WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON e.ExchangeId = s.ExchangeId
GO
```

How can I rewrite this query to be more efficient? i.e. using `WITH` keyword or some other features I might not be aware of.

Comment: Those subqueries are a likely candidate for review, as well as ensuring you have relevant indexes. Is there also a reason you're (ab)using the `NOLOCK` hint?

Comment: `WITH` isn't particularly "new" either (you're even using it in your SQL for the (ab)use of the `NOLOCK` hint). Why do you think changing the hint will help performance?

Comment: The StockPrices table in particular is quite a busy table... I thought as there are read/write queries running all the time, this select query wouldn't lock the table... ensuring all the other read/writes don't wait unnecessarily.

Comment: `NOLOCK` does not mean "use no locks". See [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start my moving your 5 subqueries into a single query. Of the 4 `TOP (1)` queries all but one of them order by `StockPriceId`, so I'm going to assume it should be the same for `YearTPrice` (which currently returns an arbitrary row).

For the `MIN` value, I use a windowed `MIN` instead.

I also remove the `NOLOCK` hints as they are clearly being abused. If you "msut" (you don't) need to have the `NOLOCK` hint against *every table* in the query then change the isolation level of the tranasction.

```sql
SELECT e.ExchangeId,
       e.ExchangeName,
       s.StockId,
       s.StockName,
       sp.StockDate,
       sp.StockPrice,
       DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate) AS YearTDate,
       spm.StockPrice AS YearTPrice,
       spm.StockDate AS LatestDate,
       spm.StockPrice AS LatestPrice,
       spm.StockPrice - sp.StockPrice AS PL,
       CASE WHEN sp.StockPrice < spm.MinPrice THEN 'Opportunity' ELSE 'None' END AS [Status]
FROM dbo.StockPrices sp
     INNER JOIN dbo.Stocks s ON s.StockId = sp.StockId
     INNER JOIN dbo.Exchanges e ON e.ExchangeId = s.ExchangeId
     --I use an outer apply, as I don't know if a row is guarenteed to be returned
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1)
                         dt.StockPrice,
                         dt.StockDate,
                         dt.MinPrice
                  FROM (SELECT ca.StockPriceId,
                               ca.StockPrice,
                               ca.StockDate,
                               MIN(StockPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY ca.StockId) AS MinPrice
                        FROM dbo.StockPrices ca
                        WHERE ca.StockId = sp.StockId
                          AND ca.StockDate = DATEADD(YEAR, -3, sp.StockDate)) dt --This isn't SARGable, so will result in a scan
                  ORDER BY dt.StockPriceId) spm;
```

of course, this is all completely untested as no sample data exists, so I have no way of knowing how much this will change your query (or even effect the results as I can't test) but it does reduce 5 or 6 scans of `StockPrices` down to 1 or 2